# Measures distance using the camera

Tags: applications, camera

I have found tools like [Smart Ruler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.sira.ruler) that helps us measure length using the screen. But for objects bigger than the screen, I imagine there are apps that use the camera and focal length to show distances and widths. If there's no such app, is it possible to use a camera or any other common phone hardware to measure spatial dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an app from the same developer that does what I wanted for buildings: [Smart Measure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.sira.measure).

> This rangefinder (telemeter) measures the distance and height of a target using trigonometry.

Comment: They also have an app called [smart distance](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.sira.distance).